# How to convert video to mp4 [javacv]

Tags: javacv

I would like to convert the video file to `.mp4`. As it works for containers like `.avi` or `.flv`, there is a problem with `.mkv`. Audio and video are out of sync for that format. I've seen [that](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/321) conversation on github and did exactly what was advised. The result was actaully the same what user `The-Crocop` had. It ends with `Try to use different formats and codecs.`.  I have a [sample](https://sample-videos.com/) video in `.mkv` container (size `1mb`). The information (among others) I got about that file from [`MediaInfo`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.4/group__lavc__core.html#gaadca229ad2c20e060a14fec08a5cc7ce) are:

- Codec ID: V_MPEG4/ISO/ASP
- Codec ID/Info: Advanced Simple Profile
- Color space: YUV
- Chroma subsampling: 4:2:0

That is the reason for my setting:

```
FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(input);
grabber.start();

FrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(output, grabber.getImageWidth(), grabber.getImageHeight(), grabber.getAudioChannels());
recorder.setVideoCodecName("h262");
recorder.setFormat("mp4");
recorder.setPixelFormat(avutil.AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P);
recorder.setVideoQuality(0);
recorder.setAudioQuality(0);
recorder.start();

Frame frame;
while ((frame = grabber.grabFrame()) != null) {
    recorder.setTimestamp(grabber.getTimestamp());
    recorder.record(frame);
}

recorder.stop();
grabber.stop();
```

`MediaInfo` says that codec used in this container is [`MPEG part 2`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.4/group__lavc__core.html#gaadca229ad2c20e060a14fec08a5cc7ce) and in the [`ffmpeg`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.4/group__lavc__core.html#gaadca229ad2c20e060a14fec08a5cc7ce) documentation I can find it as supported under `MPEG-4 part 2`, known as `h262`. I am not sure about passing `h262` as name as I can't find a [`AVCodecID`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.4/group__lavc__core.html#gaadca229ad2c20e060a14fec08a5cc7ce) for that.

What might be the reason the video and audio are out of sync in my case ?

Comment: Just use AV_CODEC_ID_H264 as codec. No need to set format, since, Javacv will find it by the file name like movie.mp4